# How to write back to command line from c# program

Tags: c#, winforms, command-line-interface, console-application

Winform app that accepts CLI arguments opens new console window when run, but i want it to run in the CLI instead and return any Console.WriteLine()'s there

This is how i split out the GUI and the console

```
static class program{
    [STAThread]
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool AllocConsole();

    static void Main(string[] args){
        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            AllocConsole();
            Console.WriteLine("Yo!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new someForm());
        }
    }
}
```

"Yo!" appears in new console window, but i want it in the command interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to your code, you need to change following:

1) Set your project type to `Console Application` in project settings page. Your `WinForms` "mode" will run as expected if command line params are not supplied.

2) Remove the call to `AllocConsole`.

3) Hide the Console Window in case your are running the WinForms mode.

Here is the complete code:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

[STAThread]
static void Main(string [] args)
{
    if (args.Length > 0)
    {              
        Console.WriteLine("Yo!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    else
    {
        ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), 0);
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }                
}
```

Comment: This makes the program run in the command window but now a console window appears when i double click on the exe along with the GUI

Comment: Still get a flash of the console before it disappears, but good enough for me