# How do I run Console and Forms at the same time? c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, testing, console

I've been trying to look for solution but neither of those helped.
I'd like program to turn on the Windows Forms and Console App at the same time. But whenever I put a code like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    NativeMethods.AllocConsole();
    Checklogs.LogLogic();
    var form = new Form1();
    NativeMethods.FreeConsole();
    Application.Run(new Form1());
    form.Show();
}
```

It only shows the console. But when i remove the Checklogs.LogLogic's code from there.
it shows everything. Anyone knows the solution?
Checlogs code:

```
public static void LogLogic()
{

    int l = 0;
    int t = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        //read
        for (l = 65; l < 91; l++)
        {
            t = GetAsyncKeyState(l);

            if (t == -32767 && GetAsyncKeyState(0x14) != 0x14)
            {
                Console.WriteLine((char)(l + 32));
            }
            else if (t == -32767 && GetAsyncKeyState(0x14) == 0x14)
            {
                Console.WriteLine((char)l);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57624997/1410246

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

`Checklogs.LogLogic();` is a blocking call. Execution wont get to `var form = new Form1();` until `LogLogic` returns, which it never does due to the infinite `while` loop.

Without pretending to understand the details of your current program or if your whole setup is a good idea (which at first glance doesn't seem to be), you'll probably get results closer to your expectation if you simply show the form (non blocking) before calling `LogLogic`:

```
...
var form = new Form1();
NativeMethods.FreeConsole();
Application.Run(new Form1());
form.Show();
Checklogs.LogLogic();
```

Comment: Won't that block the UI Thread now on `Checklogs.LogLogic();` and the UI will be unresponsive?

Comment: @RandRandom Yes, thats why I'm saying the whole set up is wrong. But he's asking why the form isn't showing, and thats what I'm answering.

Comment: @bial654321 Hard to say without understanding what you are trying to acheive; its not at all clear looking at your current code. Explain what you are trying to do, not whats wrong with your bad implementation ([XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem))

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you are trying to do but how about this:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        if (NativeMethods.AllocConsole()) //allocconsole
        {
            var th = new Thread(CommunicateWithConsole); //create a new thread and pass our endless running method, as to not block the UI Thread
            th.Start();
        }

        //register to ApplicationExit if you want to free the Console when this happens
        Application.ApplicationExit += Application_ApplicationExit;

        //show Form1
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    private static void Application_ApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NativeMethods.FreeConsole();
    }

    //our method to check the console and write to it
    private static void CommunicateWithConsole()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var x = Console.ReadLine(); //stay here till console returns a line, can be changed to Console.ReadKey()
                if (x == "Hello WinForms") //if line says this
                    Console.WriteLine("Hello ConsoleWindow"); //output this to console, waring only outputs to your console if application is not run with a debugger
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            //when we close our app and call freeconsole an IOException can occurr, handle that case
        }
    }
}

public partial class NativeMethods
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "AllocConsole")]
    [return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool AllocConsole();

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "FreeConsole")]
    [return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool FreeConsole();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you follow your program flow, it gets stuck in the while(true) loop.